# Vector Calculus proof part derivation.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, vector-analysis

I am following a proof in my vector calculus book, but I am getting stuck.

Let $T(s)$ be the the unit tangent vector at $s$
and let $k(s) = \|(T’(s))\|$ -- here $T’(s)$ is orthogonal to $T(s)$ -- and let $N(s)$ be the unit vector such that $T’(s)=k(s) \cdot N(s)$.

See photo[image]

Now, in the proof it says

differentiating 
$N(s) \cdot T(s) =0$
gives $N’(s)\cdot T(s)+N(s)\cdot T’(s) =0$.

Hence 
$N’(s) \cdot T(s)=-k(s)$. 
But I don’t see how this is derived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$N(s)\cdot T(s)=0 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\left(N(s)\cdot T(s)\right)=0 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{dN(s)}{dt}\cdot T(s)+N(s)\cdot \frac{dT(s)}{dt}=0 \\ \Rightarrow \frac{dN(s)}{dt}\cdot T(s)=-N(s)\cdot \frac{dT(s)}{dt}$

but you are told that $\frac{dT(s)}{dt}=k(s)N(s)$ so

$\frac{dN(s)}{dt}\cdot T(s)=-N(s)\cdot \left(k(s)N(s)\right)=-k(s)\left(N(s)\cdot N(s)\right)$

and $N(s)\cdot N(s)=1$ because $N(s)$ is a unit vector, so

$\frac{dN(s)}{dt}\cdot T(s)=-k(s)$